# Angular super.ngOnDestroy to unsubscribe/clean up

Tags: angular, typescript

There are several ways to unsubscribe / clean up from observables on a Angular components (by using ngOnDestroy). Which option below should be preferred and why, and is it a good idea to call `super.ngOnDestroy()`.

**Option 1**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-flights",
  templateUrl: "./flights.component.html"
})
export class FlightsComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject();

  public flights: FlightModel[];

  constructor(private readonly flightService: FlightService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.flightService
      .getAll()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(flights => (this.flights = flights));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

**Options 2**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-flights",
  templateUrl: "./flights.component.html"
})
export class FlightsComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject();

  public flights: FlightModel[];

  constructor(private readonly flightService: FlightService) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.flightService
      .getAll()
      .subscribe(flights => (this.flights = flights));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    super.ngOnDestroy();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither...

### The Problem with Either Method

Probably not the answer you expected, but consider below scenario, You have 100+ components each having an average of 2 `aysnc` properties, in total you have about 200+ subscriptions...
Now lets consider that one of your codes unfortunately was not unsubscribed and you have a **memory leak**, you now have 200+ code blocks to go through...

The other issue with the approach is that if you have to test, **you will need to test each and every `ngOnDestroy` code blocks**,

Next issue will be **Too Many Similar Code Blocks**. In both cases you will have to have the `ngOnDestroy` code blocks

### What to do?

Luckily angular provides an automatic subscription and unsubscription using `async` pipe

Let's implement This in your code...

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: "app-flights",
  templateUrl: "./flights.component.html"
})
export class FlightsComponent {
  
  flights$: Observable<FlightModel[]> = this.flightService.getAll()

  constructor(private readonly 
  flightService: FlightService) {}
}
```

Now simply wrap your html with

```html
<ng-container *ngIf='flights$ | async as flights'>
</ng-container>
```

Code made simple and now we dont need to implement any interface